# Частица "не" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Правильно написать раздельно частицу "не" в следующем предложении:
"Каждый специалист компании имеет за плечами десятки успешных проектов различного уровня сложности, направленных на решение как стандартных, так и не стандартных задач, с учетом специфики деятельности Заказчика."

Answer (score 1):

Как стандартных, так и нестандартных. Слитно. Приставка НЕ образует в данном случае слово с противоположным значением - антоним(стандартные - нестандартные)

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с предыдущим оратором, что прилагательное "**нестандартных**" пишется  слитно...только объяснение здесь несколько иное: в приведенном  случае **НЕ** с прилагательным пишется слитно, так как его можно заменить синонимом без **НЕ** (**своеобразный, оригинальный, своеобычный, самобытный, характерный, самостоятельный, особенный, свой, специфический** и т.д.) или близким по лексическому значению словосочетанием (варианты разнообразны)...